# What will the Monero Research Lab be working on in the future, after RingCT has released?

Tags: monero-research-lab, difficulty-algorithm, cuckoo-cycle

Will they be looking more into quantum proofing the Monero protocol or Cuckoo Cycle testing etc?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Monero Research Lab Publications MRL-0001 to MRL-0005 have been [published](https://lab.getmonero.org/).

**MRL-0006 - Difficulty Adjustment Algorithms in Cryptocurrency Protocols**
have been [started](https://github.com/monero-project/research-lab/tree/master/publications/MRL-0006%20-%20Difficulty%20Adjustment%20Algorithms%20in%20Cryptocurrency%20Protocols).
According to [fluffypony](https://github.com/monero-project/research-lab/issues/3)

> The difficulty research that Surae was working on is quite extensive, but incomplete.

EDIT: as of November 17th, it appears MRL-0006 will be renamed [MRL-0007](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/2748/24).

> Someone would have to pick it up and run with it, as Surae is basically burnt out on difficulty and has moved on to other challenges:)

A version of **MRL-0008 - Ring Multisignature** [exists](https://shnoe.files.wordpress.com/2016/03/mrl-0008_april28.pdf) but is not published yet.

Answer (score 7):

Additionally to what Clement J. said, there are a lot of potential future reserach tasks on the [Monero Design & Development goals](https://getmonero.org/design-goals/), including Research goals on the bottom half of that page.

[image]