# Is there MRL-0007? What topic is it about?

Tags: monero-research-lab, research

I see from a previous [post](https://monero.stackexchange.com/q/1645/506) that MRL-0001~0005 are complete and published while MRL-0006 and MRL-0008 are still ongoing, but I've never heard anything about MRL-0007. Is there such a thing? If so, what issue does it address?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [this comment](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/1345#issuecomment-261261934) from fluffypony it appears that MRL-007 was skipped and does not (currently) exist.

> @kenshi84 any chance you could do a formal write-up and submit it to the Monero Research Lab repo for us to publish? It would go as MRL-0006, and the current WIP that is MRL-0006 would be moved out to 7 or something.

@kenshi84 [confirmed](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/1345#issuecomment-261267185) a willingness to begin working on a formal write up (to become MRL-006) for the topic in the [one-time receiving address](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/2741/11) idea that led to this [pull request](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/1345)

> @fluffypony Sure, I'd be honored to be able to publish at MRL:)

The previous [MRL-006](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/1646/11) will be renamed MRL-007 and [Difficulty Adjustment Algorithms](https://github.com/monero-project/research-lab/tree/master/publications/MRL-0006%20-%20Difficulty%20Adjustment%20Algorithms%20in%20Cryptocurrency%20Protocols) in Cryptocurrency Protocols research will continue.

Comment: Funny answer considering @kenshi84 asked this question. :-)